# PHPMailer sending email and returning blank page with echo

Tags: php, email, xampp, phpmailer

Email sends correctly, but then everything on my submission page disappears (although in the url it says it is the same page) except the echo statement saying 'Message sent successfully'.

I want to have a 'congratulations' page or something less cheesy to greet the user after they are sent the validation email...

I've tried searching the class.phpmailer.php for a redirect function but theres nothing. I'm sure its something simple but I cant seem to locate whats causing this.

```
<?php
require ('/config.inc.php');
require '../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    if(mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1){
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Host     = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "censored@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "censored";

    //Set who the message is to be sent from
    $mail->setFrom('censored@gmail.com');
    //Set an alternative reply-to address
    $mail->addReplyTo('censored@gmail.com');
    //Set who the message is to be sent to
    $mail->addAddress($trimmed['email']);
    //Set the subject line
    $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer mail() test';
    //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
    //convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
    $mail->msgHTML('Thank you for registering at The Circle Of Pi. To activate your account,
         please click on this link:\n\n' . BASE_URL . 'activate.php?x=' . urlencode($e) . "&y=$a");

    //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
    //Attach an image file
    //$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

    //send the message, check for errors
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Message sent!1";
    }
         exit();
    }else {
        echo '<p class=\"error\">You could not be registered due to a system error. We apologize 
        for any inconvenience.</p>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<p class = \"error\">That email address has already been registered. If you have
         forgotten your password, use the link at the right to have your password sent to you</p>';
    }
    }   else {
        echo '<p class = \"error\">Please try again.</p>';
    }
    mysqli_close($dbc);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Could you show us some of your code? So we can see whats going on?

Comment: PHPMailer doesn't issue redirects; that's not its job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your request is `POST` then you're calling `exit()` after 'Message sent!1' echo.

```
else {
    echo "Message sent!1";
}
exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

On your:

```
<form method="post">
```

Add a action to it such as:

```
<form method="post" action="{pickaname}.php">
```

and create a file called {pickaname}.php and make it when all the data is inserted it will redirect the user to your congratulations page.